# How to connect to oracle apex environment from my android browser

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with oracle apex 5.1 on my Laptop at: http://192.168.1.6:8181/APEX/ at a local network and every thing is working correctly, I want to open the same at my mobile web browser.

When I navigate to 
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:16230997599016: from mobile; the login page appears normally, **But** when I navigate to: http://192.168.1.6:8181/APEX/ I face unable to connect message in browser.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anything to do with Apex really. Is your Android device connected to the same LAN as your laptop? If so is there a firewall on your laptop that's preventing access to that port?

Comment: And sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes the mobile phone is on the same network with laptop, in addition the I can access to the same URL from other laptop on the same network, but from mobile no way.